# MPMoviePlayerController prepareToPlay not working with HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to play an HTTP live streaming video using a `MPMoviePlayerController` object, inside a modal view controller. If I run the code like this, everything works fine. I get a `MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying` notification, and the video plays.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(moviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange:)  name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification  object:nil];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"];
    self.moviePlayerController = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url] autorelease]; 
    self.moviePlayerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,416);
    self.moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    self.moviePlayerController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayerController.view];  
    self.moviePlayerController.fullscreen = NO;  
    [self.moviePlayerController play]; 
}
```

I would prefer to use the `prepareToPlay` method, so that I can show a loading indicator, and for a nicer experience. However, I don't seem to be able to get this working. No `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification` ever gets called, and the stream doesn't play. The activity indicator just sits there spinning forever.

I've confirmed that `prepareToPlay` does get called, but nothing else seems to happen after that. I've also confirmed that this code works fine with a local movie file. It just seems to be with HTTP Live Streaming which fails. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(moviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange:)  name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification  object:nil];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"];
    self.moviePlayerController = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url] autorelease]; 

    [self registerForMovieNotifications]; 
}

- (void)registerForMovieNotifications {
    //movie is ready to play notifications
    if ([self.moviePlayerController respondsToSelector:@selector(loadState)]) {
        //this is a 3.2+ device
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:) name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];       
        self.moviePlayerController.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
        [self.moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
    } else {
        //pre-3.2 device
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePreloadDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification object:nil];
    }

    //movie has finished notification
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
}

- (void) moviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"playbackDidChanged");
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = notification.object;
    MPMoviePlaybackState playbackState = moviePlayer.playbackState;
    if(playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped) {
        NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped");
    } else if(playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying) {
        NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying");
    } else if(playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused) {
        NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused");
    } else if(playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted) {
        NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted");
    } else if(playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward) {
        NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward");
    } else if(playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward) {
        NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward");
    }
}

//3.2+ devices
- (void)moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"load state changed");

    //unless state is unknown, start playback
    if ([self.moviePlayerController loadState] != MPMovieLoadStateUnknown) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];

        self.moviePlayerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,416);
        self.moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
        self.moviePlayerController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayerController.view];  
        self.moviePlayerController.fullscreen = NO;  
        [self.moviePlayerController play]; 
    }
}

//pre 3.2 devices
- (void) moviePreloadDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification  {
    // Remove observer
    [[NSNotificationCenter  defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification object:nil];
    [self.moviePlayerController play];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why, but I was able to solve this by moving the line `self.moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;` out of the `moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:` method, and into the `viewDidLoad` method.

Anyone have any ideas why this made a difference?